# In the LHC, how is the proton separated from the electron in the hydrogen?

Tags: hydrogen, large-hadron-collider, protons, accelerator-physics, ions

I know that we use protons in the LHC. So my question is, how is the proton separated from the electron in the hydrogen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the proton for collision in lhc is made?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226326/)